# regular expression - NOT match a pattern

Tags: regex

I have the following regular expression to match an email address:

```
^([a-zA-Z0-9])+([a-zA-Z0-9._%+-])+@([a-zA-Z0-9_.-])+\.(([a-zA-Z]){2,6})$
```

How can I modify this if I want to match everything BUT an email address?
Instinctively, I think of something like

```
!(^([a-zA-Z0-9])+([a-zA-Z0-9._%+-])+@([a-zA-Z0-9_.-])+\.(([a-zA-Z]){2,6})$)
```

but I know that's not how regular expressions work.

Comment: Same as what you got `^(?![a-zA-Z0-9])+([a-zA-Z0-9._%+-])+@([a-zA-Z0-9_.-])+\.(([a-zA-Z]){2,6}$).+$`

Comment: Whatever tool you are using may have an option to negate the match. For example, grep has "-v" option

Comment: @sln did the trick, thanks

Comment: Added it as an answer!

Comment: @noclist, you can use the SKIP and FAIL verbs. Check this https://regex101.com/r/BfmmXx/1/

Answer (score 0):

Match anything *other than an email address*

`^(?![a-zA-Z0-9])+([a-zA-Z0-9._%+-])+@([a-zA-Z0-9_.-])+\.(([a‌​-zA-Z]){2,6}$).+$`

```
^        # BOS
         # Not an email address
(?![a-zA-Z0-9])+([a-zA-Z0-9._%+-])+@([a-zA-Z0-9_.-])+\.(([a‌​-zA-Z]){2,6}$)
.+       # Ok, match whatever this string contains
$        # EOS
```